# Trying to convert this bash line to Python 2.6

Tags: bash, python-2.6

I need help converting this bash line to Python 2.6:

```
# Bash line
ssh -X ${var} users |tr ' ' '\n' |uniq |tr '\n' ' '
```

The output of this command will go to a variable as a string. So far, this is what I have in Python 2.6:

```
# Python implementation
string = subprocess.call("ssh -X {0} users |tr \' \' \'\n\' |uniq |tr \'\n\' \' \'".format(var), shell=True)
```

Is this correct, or is there a better way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to escape single quotes inside a double-quoted string.

Comment: Why do you need `-X`? You're not doing anything that uses X11.

Comment: Python 2 is dead now; but even if you can't move to version 3 immediately, certainly at least use 2.7.

Comment: ...but you do need to double backslashes in a regular Python string. (In recent Python versions there's a "raw" string type which doesn't require backslashes to be doubled.)

Comment: But it would be better to replace the rest of the pipeline with native Python and just call `subprocess.check_output(['ssh', var, 'users'])` in a subprocess, without `shell=True`.

Comment: Also, `subprocess.call()` doesn't return a string at all! But you can switch to `check_output()` if you upgrade to 2.7, or reimplement it using the (clumsy but well documented) `Popen` + `communicate()` sequence.

Comment: Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188